# Why is my gaussian GLM better than my poisson GLM for count data?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression

Given the following code:

```
df<-structure(list(N = c(97L, 97L, 90L, 111L, 108L, 83L, 72L, 107L, 
156L, 159L, 92L, 72L, 228L, 115L, 182L, 216L, 233L, 167L, 93L, 
204L, 55L, 185L, 163L, 65L, 103L, 107L, 182L, 293L, 91L, 52L, 
176L, 110L, 113L, 225L, 119L, 132L), x = c(46.7228252110461, 
46.6819871518318, 47.270241844776, 47.9898485462862, 47.8396257393914, 
47.796127088125, 47.57147041175, 48.1588702768176, 48.5000199350821, 
49, 48.5000968372371, 48.5753856028303, 49.312918878543, 48.3968587440564, 
49.0777317648583, 48.3057829872496, 48.0700449039265, 48.5510457147943, 
48.5829394151059, 50.0083191998552, 47.6813628201493, 49.3598781549173, 
50.539012213558, 49.5089784216086, 49.1222148031355, 48.7737067042595, 
49.3737319261229, 49.7938972671776, 49.5780549528089, 48.5000035215272, 
49.5, 49.0954381376657, 49.5358040507565, 48.989997312362, 49.5, 
48.0694101885463)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L
))

lm_g<-glm(N~x,df,family=gaussian())
lm_p<-glm(N~x,df,family=poisson())

print( paste("Gaussian model better?", AIC(lm_g)<AIC(lm_p) ) )
```

Why is the AIC of the gaussian model better than the one of the poisson model even though the variable N is count data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AIC depends on the likelihood of the distribution. As such, you cannot directly compare these models.

A feasible way to do so is to

1. specify a relevant scoring function for your problem, e.g. mean Poisson deviance
2. estimate its value using (cross-)validation